# Linked List Null Pointer Exception

Tags: linked-list

I'm not sure what is wrong here, I've looked at online, I've seen slightly different way people are implementing deleting a linked list, but I'm not sure what's wrong and why I'm getting a null pointer exception

```
class GfG
{
    Node deleteNode(Node head, int x)
    {
    // Your code here   
    //checks the first nodes value, if found, changes head to equal next node
        Node current = head;
        if(head.data == x){
            head = head.next;
           return head;
        }
        
        while(current != null){
                //if statement checks for next nodes data value for comparions
                if(current.next.data == x){
                current.next = current.next.next;
                return head;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
            return head;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code.

Comment: Line 100, you need to check if current.next != null before checking on its data.

Answer (score 1):

Note: don't post picture of your code. Post your code as is.

You don't check in your while loop that you have a next element.

If you are at the end of your list `current.next == null` and `current.next.data` fire a null pointer exception.

Comment: ok so I fixed that, but now it doesn't remove update the linked list with the removed node, is there something I'm not understanding with this line? current.next = current.next.next;

Comment: If you want to remove the node current.next, then current.next = current.next.next should do the work. As I don't know the current state of your code, I can't help you much on that.